# SQL subquery alternative

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a simple select sub query which is taking lot of time to execute.

```
SELECT EMPID, UPDATETIME 
FROM TIME_DETAILS T1
WHERE T1.EVENTNAME = 'ENROLL' 
  AND T1.STATUS = 'BEGIN'
  AND (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM TIME_DETAILS T2 
       WHERE T1.EMPID = T2.EMPID 
         AND T2.EVENTNAME = 'ENROLL'
         AND T2.STATUS = 'END') = 0;
```

Kindly suggest possible modifications which can improve the performance or any way to skip the sub query

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also describe what the logic should be doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First change the query to `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT EMPID, UPDATETIME
FROM TIME_DETAILS T1
WHERE T1.EVENTNAME = 'ENROLL' AND
      T1.STATUS = 'BEGIN' AND 
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM TIME_DETAILS T2
                  WHERE T2.EMPID = T1.EMPID AND
                        T2.EVENTNAME = 'ENROLL' AND
                        T2.STATUS = 'END'
                 );
```

Then you want indexes on `TIME_DETAILS(EVENTNAME, STATUS)` AND `TIME_DETAILS(EMPID, EVENTNAME, STATUS)`.

You might also find that it is faster to simply use window functions:

```
SELECT EMPID, UPDATETIME
FROM (SELECT td.*,
             SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'END' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY EMPID, EVENTNAME) as cnt_end 
      FROM TIME_DETAILS td
     ) td
WHERE STATUS = 'BEGIN' AND cnt_end = 0;
```

For this, you only want an index on `(EMPID, EVENTNAME, STATUS)`.

Or aggregation:

```
select empid, max(case when status = 'BEGIN' then updatetime end)
from time_details td
where eventname = 'ENROLL' and
      status in ('BEGIN', 'END')
group by empid
having max(status) = 'BEGIN'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was thinking of converting the subquery to aggregate but not sure if I'm getting that right. What if the status values are START and FINISH in place of BEGIN and END ?

Comment: @technocrat . . . You would replace the corresponding string literals in the queries.